turning off auto login for Msal2Provider
I have a react application and I am using the Msal2Provider and global providers from microsoft.
import { Providers } from "@microsoft/mgt-element";
import { Msal2Provider } from "@microsoft/mgt-msal2-provider";

Providers.globalProvider = new Msal2Provider({
  clientId: import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENT_ID!,
  authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${import.meta.env.VITE_TENANT_ID}`,
  redirectUri: import.meta.env.VITE_REDIRECT_URI,
  scopes: ['user.read'],
});

I've been using the Login component from @microsoft/mgt-react  which is nice it has a nice login button that takes you to office 365 login and then it shows the logged in user and their picture with a logout button.  but the problem is when I click the logout button it does indeed logout but the moment I go back into the home page of the react app It immediately tries to log me back in without me even clicking the button.  This would be fine except I have a multi tenant application with 2 login buttons one for each tenant so I want when I log out it does not try to auto logon until I click the Login button.  is there anyway to achieve this? I did not see any kind of donotautologin prop on the Login component.
